# Add information table from input

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a quotation, I have created the database with records, what I want to achieve is that through this input rows are added to the table below, since it is a quote that can be cancelled, I would like the data to be added if temporarily alter the quotation table, when confirmed then the list will be added to the "quote" table.

[image: Form]

Comment: `alter`, as in an actual `alter table` query, or just "modify the values in an existing record"? There's a pretty major difference there...

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional table for temporary quotes.  Records could be moved over from the temporary table to the final table when you're ready to commit.

OR

Add the temporaries to a `$_SESSION` and commit when ready.  The drawback is they will go away if the session is lost.

Comment: ok, I think I'll go with the second option, the problem is not how to show HTML without relying on the database.

1. I want to enter the html code and display the information of the new code, be putting more codes temporarily.

2. when the order is confirmed that information is passed to the database.

3. how it's done? Ajax?

Comment: You tell us.  Ajax is how I'd do it, personally.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, in a public minutes another question with the code to help me polish, best regards.